# Form is submitting when it shouldn't do

Tags: javascript

There is a problem with my jsfiddle application [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/DQUKN/3/). When you open the fiddle then you will see a textarea, please follow steps below (in any borwser but IE):

1:Type in a question in the textarea

2: Click on the "AddQuestion" button. The question you have entered will be appended in the table below.

3: Delete all of the text in the textarea you have just added in the table below

4: Now click on the "Submit Details" button below.

Now as you can see it is trying to submit the details and go into a new page. This should not happen because I stated in my validation function that if a textarea which is appended in a table is empty or "", then display an alert stating "Please Enter in a Valid Question". Even if the question is valid, it should display a confirmation box stating if you want to proceed or not.

When the submit button is clicked it should follow the "myClickHandler" but why isn't it doing this?

Comment: Why are you mixing plain JavaScript and jQuery like that?

Comment: Because I did a similar validation function in another php file but that user javascript while the file I am working on now contains jquery.

Answer (score 0):

**plan a:**

```
$("#addQuestionBtn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

**plan b:**

```
$('#enter').submit(function() {  
    ....  
    return false;  
});
```

add "return false;" in the end

**quote:**

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

The event handler can be bound to the form:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {  
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');  
    return false;  
});
```

Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler. We can trigger the event manually when another element is clicked:

Answer (score 0):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to cancel the form submission.

BTW, you probably meant `textAreaO.length`, not `textAreaO.value.length` that throws `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

The textAreaO variable in the validate() function may contain more than 1 item from the selection. Iterate through each item and do the checking for each:

```
var isValid = true;
 $(textAreaO).each(function() {
     isValid = isValid && //insert your validation check here;
 });

 if(!isValid) alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
```